# WebJob Python Error ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, azure, numpy, web-applications, webjob

I'm getting the following error when I try to schedule a Python file that is zipped inside a folder with its libraries.

The file uses only the pandas library, but numpy is a dependency of it, so I copied the folder of all the dependencies of pandas, like, pandas, numpy, dateutil, pytz.

But I keep getting the error, JUST ON THE WEBJOB, WEB APP AZURE, but location on my PC works normally.

```
[03/07/2019 14:39:00 > a4d03a: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[03/07/2019 14:39:01 > a4d03a: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected: Job file 'testeWEBJOB\test.py' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
[03/07/2019 14:39:28 > a4d03a: SYS INFO] Run script 'test.py' with script host - 'PythonScriptHost'
[03/07/2019 14:39:28 > a4d03a: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ]   File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ]     import pandas as pd
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ]   File "D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\TESTE\zqwhvklh.hch\testeWEBJOB\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ]     "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: ERR ] ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[03/07/2019 14:39:29 > a4d03a: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello, do you have more issues about the question? if the answer works for you, please help mark it as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below steps:

1.Nav to azure portal -> your web app -> in the left blade, select Extensions -> then add the python extension(the one you used):

[image]

[image]

2. Then nav to kudu site(`https://your_web_app_name.scm.azurewebsites.net`) -> In the Debug Console at the top, select CMD -> then nav to the python install dir(in my case, it's D:\home\python364x64>) -> then execute the cmd `"pip install numpy"`

Nav to kudu site:

[image]

In kudu site, click the Debug Console -> CMD, and change directory to D:\home\python364x64

[image]

Comment: I have followed your steps but am still getting `ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`. Do you know what the problem is? The folders `numpy` and `numpy-1.16.4.dist-info` are now in D:\home\python364x64\Lib\site-packages